# Read Wildcard As Asterisk

Tags: excel, vba

I had a piece of code commissioned earlier this week (cheaper to have an expert write it than for me to spend a week trying to!). However, when putting it use I've hit a bit of a snag.

The macro looks at a name on one excel worksheet, matches it to a list of names and associated ID numbers on a different worksheet, then inserts the ID on the first worksheet. This was all fine until I started using it on real data.

Here's some sample data (all of this information is in one cell...):

WARHOL*, Andy

PETO, John F

D3 GRECO, Emilio -20th C

HASELTINE, William Stanley

D3 DALI, Salvador

D3 SOSNO, Sacha

WEGMAN**, WILLIAM

One asterisk means it's a print, two a photograph, D3 a sculpture, and nothing a painting.

When I run the code with this data, it sees * as a wildcard, and so will always insert the ID of the first variation of the artist in the sheet. What I need is a way for the macro to not read it as a wildcard.

I did some research, and found that inserting ~ before * negates the wildcard properties. How would I make my code do this? I've discovered the main issue of having code written by someone else... You might not understand it!

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub match_data()
'ctrl+r
On Error GoTo errh

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim r1, r2, i, exc As Long
Dim fp As Range

Sheets("Data").Activate

r1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
r2 = Sheets("List").Cells(Sheets("List").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'MsgBox r1 & r2

exc = 0

For i = 2 To r1
    If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
        With Sheets("List").Range("B2:B" & r2)
            Set fp = .Find(Range("B" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not fp Is Nothing Then
            Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone
            Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("List").Range("A" & fp.Row).Value
        Else
            Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone
            Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            exc = exc + 1
        End If

    End With
End If
Next i

MsgBox "There are " & exc & " exceptions."

errh:
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Oh also, I would need to do this for the list of names and ID's wouldn't I? If so, that only needs doing once, so if you could give me a hint about that too, I'd be so grateful!

Thanks!

PS I know the system we are using at the moment absolutely sucks (definitely not 3rd form normalised!), but we are fast running out of time and money, and need to get our product up and running ASAP!

EDIT: To clarify, here is a pic of the spreadsheets I'm working with... Obviously in cells A14 and A15 I wanted the ID numbers 11 & 12 respectively

[image: Clarification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have solved the problem! I had a play around with changing the variables in the Find and Replace box.

If I put ~* in both the find AND replace boxes, and uncheck Match entire cell contents, I can replace all of the * with ~* (really don't understand that but oh well!)

So I do this on the Data worksheet, but NOT on the List worksheet, run the macro as normal and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to tell the stars from the planets:

```
Sub StaryNight()
    Dim s As String, OneStar As String, TwoStar As String, ThreeStar As String

    OneStar = "*"
    TwoStar = "**"
    ThreeStar = "***"
    t = Range("A1").Text
    ary = Split(t, ",")
    s = ary(0)

    If Right(s, 3) = ThreeStar Then
        MsgBox "scupture"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Right(s, 2) = TwoStar Then
        MsgBox "photograph"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Right(s, 1) = OneStar Then
        MsgBox "print"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Painting"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, I may have misspoke (mistyped?)... Upon reading your answer, I realised my question wasn't as clear as it could be. I have a column of names, but the surname, first name and possible asterisks are in the same cell!